# jQuery IE exception 'nodes' is null or not an object On $(element).trigger('someevent')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

`$('body').trigger("ReciveData");` it works just fine on Firefox, Chrome, Safari
then I come to IE its send me exception this the message:

> 'nodes' is null or not an object

My code:

```
try {
  
  var tempId = data.substring(0, 4);
  
  if (ServiceCallerObject.TemplateId == tempId) {
    UtillsObject.WriteToLog('Service System Action Request Data On Template Id:' + ServiceCallerObject.TemplateId + ' Recived Message:' + data, 'debug');
    ServiceCallerObject.MessageData = ServiceCallerObject._doSuccessOutputParser(ServiceCallerObject.TemplateId, data);
    
    UtillsObject.WriteToLog('Service System Action Param Converted Into Objected', 'info');
    $('body').trigger("ReciveData");
  }
} catch (e) {
  ServiceCallerObject.IsCallActive = false;
  ServiceCallerObject.IsStillWaitForCall = false;
  UtillsObject.WriteToLog('Service System Action Exeption: {MSG: ' + e.message + ' ,File:' + e.fileName + ' ,Line:' + e.lineNumber + ' ,Type:' + e.name + ' }', 'Debug');
  UtillsObject.WriteToLog('Service System Action Request Error In Data On Template Id:' + ServiceCallerObject.TemplateId + ' Recived Message:' + data, 'error');
  $('body').trigger("ReciveDataError");
}
```

How do I fix this in order to make my application working?

Comment: Can you post the handler for the `ReciveDataError` event?  The problem is probably there.

Comment: its costume event its happend in diffrent file same as ReciveData but what make at happen its the trigger its self

Comment: just found out the file that make at its may u can help bit more
Webpage error details:
Message: 'nodes' is null or not an object
Line: 429
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/18Bet/Shared/Scripts/Extrnal/jquery.tmpl.js

Comment: just found what make see the bug i opened https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/issues/153

Comment: Found a fix its happend when you dont close a tag on the template